# Query another database using Prisma

Tags: node.js, sql-server, prisma

I am already using Prisma as an ORM for a Postgres DB. I need to run a simple raw query on a SQL Server DB. I do not need to use any of the ORM features like the Prisma schema, migrations, etc. Is it possible to do with Prisma? I am trying to minimize dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create two PrismaClient Instances, one for the PostgresDB and other for SQL Server.

Here's a GitHub Issue on how you can implement it: [#2443](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118)